# PHP function for calculating step_size

Tags: php

I am looking for a PHP function to get the "step_size".

Example:

```
0.00001000 = 5
0.00000100 = 6
0.00010000 = 4
```

Thanks for your time :)

Martijn

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by *step_size*.  Also please add what you have tried so far.

Comment: Use strpos function for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a [log10()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.log10) function. This code:

```
echo log10(1.0 / 0.00001000);
echo log10(1.0 / 0.00000100);
echo log10(1.0 / 0.00010000);
```

Will return `564`.

Then again this might totally not be what you want.

Comment: I was not aware of this functionality :) Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Martijn!

You can use basic log function:

```
// 5
echo log(0.00001000, 0.1);

// 6
echo log(0.00000100, 0.1);

// 4
echo log(0.00010000, 0.1);
```

Comment: This is also a good possibility. The log10() function is slightly more efficient at calculating power 10 logarithms, but the extra division offsets that to a large extend (measured in PHP 7.4.13).

Comment: Thanks for your help! I was not aware of this functionality :)